# Explain how this map between an ellipsoid and sphere is derived.

Tags: geometry, functions, spheres

Let $$S^2=\{ (x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \} $$ and $$E=\{ (x,y,z) | \frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} =1 \} $$
Let the map $f: S^2 \to E$ be defined as $$f(x,y,z)=(ax,by,cz)$$
I don't understand how this map takes an element of $S^2$ and sends it to $E$, visually I can see that this map just takes a point in the unit sphere and scales it, but algebraically I can't see how $f$ does that.

$f$ takes a point $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ to the point $(ax,by,cz)$ such that $$\frac{a^2x^2}{a^2} +\frac{b^2y^2}{b^2}+\frac{c^2z^2}{c^2} =x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
But that's just the unit circle, I obviously have made a terrible mistake in my reasoning but I can't spot it, can you explain?

My apologies if this is a trivial question.

Comment: I see nothing strange with your reasoning. You start with $(x,y,z)\in S^2$, and by inspection you have $(ax,by,cz)\in E$. What is terrible about that?

Comment: No that's not the unit sphere. You have a problem with your notations. The point you obtain has coordinates $x'=ax,\;  y'=by,\;z'=cz$, so it satisfies the equation $$\frac{x'^2}{a^2}+\frac{y'^2}{b^2}+\frac{z'^2}{c^2}=x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$$